# Associated function without explicit return is error[E0308]: mismatched types

Tags: rust

I have the struct `Queue` and `new` associated function which compile fine:

```
pub struct Queue {
    older: Vec<char>,
    younger: Vec<char>,
}

impl Queue {
    pub fn new() -> Queue {
        let q = Queue {
            older: Vec::new(),
            younger: Vec::new(),
        };
        q
    }
}
```

I changed the new function:

```
impl Queue {
    pub fn new() -> Queue {
        Queue {
            older: Vec::new(),
            younger: Vec::new(),
        };
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:7:27
   |
7  |       pub fn new() -> Queue {
   |  ___________________________^
8  | |         Queue {
9  | |             older: Vec::new(),
10 | |             younger: Vec::new(),
11 | |         };
   | |          - help: consider removing this semicolon
12 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected struct `Queue`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `Queue`
              found type `()`
```

Why I get the below error. What is wrong with the function in my version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you don't have an explicit return statement in your function, the expression after the last statement is returned. A statement is an expression or a declaration followed by a semicolon. In this function:

```
pub fn new() -> Queue {
    let q = Queue { older: Vec::new(), younger: Vec::new() };
    q
}
```

The expression after the last statement is `q`, so that is what is returned from the function. But in this function:

```
pub fn new() -> Queue {
    Queue { older: Vec::new(), younger: Vec::new() };
}
```

There is no expression after the last statement. So the rust compiler automatically inserts the `()` expression, also known as the unit expression. That's why the compiler is suggesting that you remove the semicolon, then that line is no longer a statement, but an expression. Follow that suggestion.